# Apache Wicket 1.6 or higher version does not support visural-wicket

Tags: wicket

As we know, visural-wicket is a light-weight wicket component, loosely coupled and to be easily integrated into any existing Wicket application.

Currently, I am updating wicket 1.5 to a higher version(mostly to wicket 1.8) in my project. And I see visural-wicket is designed for use with Wicket 1.5 or less.

is there any alternative for visural-wicket in the higher version like wicket 1.8 so that all the features of this can be migrated/implemented in up-gradation Or any suggestion on this will be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [Wicket JQuery UI](http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/). It has both jQuery and KendoUI components.

The other supported library is [Wiquery](https://github.com/wicketstuff/wiquery), but it is maintained as much as to compile with newer versions of Wicket. Nothing new has been added to it in the last few years.

Comment: thanks  for the suggestion.I am thinking to go for Wicket Jquery.